# What is this colourful insect with a large thorn?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Someone sent me the picture so I don't have a lot of details. Is it a real insect or is it fake?

Comment: It might not be fake, it looks like a [thorn bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehopper)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @Kiritee mentioned this is actually a [treehopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehopper#Morphology), due to thier unusual shape they are of long interest of naturalists.

This is a female [*Umbonia crassicornis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbonia_crassicornis).

Here's a female with her colourful nymphs captured by
[C. D. S. Molinari](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cdesoto/14047158233)
.

[image]

**Facts:**

- The females have a pointed pronotal horn (spike), the males' are blunt, with a flat top.
- The adults display variation in colour and size.
- The pointed pronotal horn is an adaptation as the insectivorous birds mistake them as [thorns (on stem)](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-nIhUdG8XnZY/UukBD7YzycI/AAAAAAAAcUQ/VnG_uEKzaqI/s1600/DSCN4857edd.jpg) and do not consume them.

> This is a variable species as to size, color and structure, particularly the pronotal horn of males (w*hich is more angled posteriorly than the females'* and often somewhat expanded apically).
>
> This tall, *essentially perpendicular* thorn-like pronotum discourages birds and other predators from eating it, if only by mistakenly confusing it with a thorn.
>
> Typically, the adult is green or yellow with reddish lines and brownish markings.
>
> The range of this species is from Northern South America all the way to Mexico and Florida. Its preferred hosts are ornamental and fruit trees of subtropical regions.

- Parental care: The females on sensing an intruder would rush to her nymphs and would charge the offender by kicking her legs, fanning her wings and sometimes even buzzing. The females communicate with the nymphs to ensure that they are in a group.

  References:
  [Encyclopedia of Land invertebrate behaviour](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=sDpagGxJw3AC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=Umbonia%20crassicornis%20wings%20fly%20female&source=bl&ots=SlmZxTZd20&sig=-ZevI328YXAK4KysCtC0Hs_Xvuk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_tL6ZmYXTAhXMuI8KHZLNA1cQ6AEIOzAI#v=onepage&q=Umbonia%20crassicornis%20wings%20fly%20female&f=false), [Encyclopedia of Insects](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ip57QSMCRk4C&pg=PA504&lpg=PA504&dq=Umbonia%20crassicornis%20wings%20fly%20female&source=bl&ots=yzNDA6W9P7&sig=pVCkOKKA00BdhVsf8jm3uLDBg20&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_tL6ZmYXTAhXMuI8KHZLNA1cQ6AEITTAM#v=onepage&q=Umbonia%20crassicornis%20wings%20fly%20female&f=false) and [Libraries of life](http://www.libraries-of-life.org/invertnet-collection-network-the-thorn-bug.html)

**Picture References:**

1. [A female with eggs](https://www.flickr.com/photos/costarica1/15738900660).
2. [Two males](http://www.colinhuttonphotography.com/truebugs/h523E446C#h523e446c) (blunt top)
3. [Original size](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-nIhUdG8XnZY/UukBD7YzycI/AAAAAAAAcUQ/VnG_uEKzaqI/s1600/DSCN4857edd.jpg)

**Good reads:**

1. [**Thornbug to Thornbug-The inside story of insect song**](http://www.naturalhistorymag.com/picks-from-the-past/12497/thornbug-to-thornbug)
2. [**Libraries of life**](http://www.libraries-of-life.org/invertnet-collection-network-the-thorn-bug.html) (audio clips)

Comment: Your edits really elevated this answer. Nice picture :). +1.

Comment: Wow, are the wings functional?

Comment: @AntonSherwood Yes, they are. The males are detectable when they fly from one branch to the another in search of female.